# Почему при отправке формы на почту приходят неформатируемые данные?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, форматирование

Интересует вопрос: почему при отправке формы на почту приходят данные в неформатируемом виде (в одну строчку) и как это исправить?

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['email']))
   {
echo "Не переданы данные!";
return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// create email body and send it 
$to = 'aomeone@some.ru'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Вопрос с сайта some.ru";
$email_body = "Заполнена форма \"Задать вопрос\" \n\r".
 "Данные отправителя\r\nИмя: $name\r\n".
 "Email: $email \r\n".
 "Вопрос: $message";

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@some.ru \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email"; 
mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=',$email_body,$headers);
return true; 
?>
```

Comment: Перед тем как пользоваться HTML сначала надо узнать, что это такое

Comment: +[Mail injection](http://phpfaq.ru/tech/mail) во всей красе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактируйте тело письма тегами, вы же отправляете html. и не зачем кодировать сабж.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'kkorushkin@gmail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Вопрос с сайта some.ru";
$email_body = "Заполнена форма \"Задать вопрос\" <br/>".
"Данные отправителя<br/>Имя: $name<br/>".
"Email: $email <br/>".
"Вопрос: $message";

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@some.ru \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как это незачем?

Comment: это не относится в основному вопросу, просто я бы рекомендовал так. Не понятно,зачем вы кодируте сабж.  Эта инструкция: ** '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?='**  не нужна, вы уже указали чарсет в заголовках.

Comment: @kff залезая в очередь проверок, следует выбирать вопросы, в которых хоть что-то смыслишь. Там есть кнопочка "пропустить" для всех остальных.

Comment: Подредактировал ответ. Если считаете ответ неверным, поясните,что не так.